# Faulhaber's formula modulo $p^2$

Tags: number-theory

What is the Faulhaber's Formula modulo $p^2$ (where $p$ is a prime)? The formula gives the result for even $k$ but for odd $k$ it fails to give the result. Infact for odd $k$ the power sum must be $0$ always if we follow the Faulhaber's formula which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simplest to use Pascal's identity:

$$ (n+1)^{i+1} - 1 = \sum_{j=0}^i {i+1 \choose j} \sum_{k=1}^n k^j $$

Let $A_m$ be the $p-1 \times p-1$ upper triangular matrix with rows and columns labelled $0, 1, \ldots, p-2$, and

$$a_{ij} = \cases{{i+1 \choose j} & $j \le i$\cr
                   0 & otherwise\cr} $$
Note that the diagonal elements are $1,2,\ldots, p-1$, so this is invertible mod $p^2$, and the inverse gives us $\sum_{k=1}^n k^j \mod p^2$ for $j = 0, \ldots, p-2$ as linear combinations of $(n+1)^{i+1}-1$, $i=0 \ldots p-2$.
However, it won't work for $p-1$.

EDIT:  In fact, $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p-1} \mod p^2$ seems to have period $p^3$, not $p^2$, in $n$.